# Pro AngularJS Book Cart Widget not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working through the Pro AngularJS book by Adam Freeman and in Chapter 7, when creating the widget for the cart, it won't render in the navbar like it should.  I've compared and even gone back to paste the provided source code over mine and both ways, the widget still does not render, (where `<cart-summary />` is, but everything else does.  I've checked the errata for the book and there is nothing published so I'm completely stuck at this point.  I have a feeling it might be one of those things that is looking me right in the face but I'm not having any luck.  Thanks in advance!  Here is my code:

-app.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" ng-app="sportsStore">
    <head>
        <title>SportsStore</title>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.css">
        <script>
          angular.module("sportsStore", ["customFilters", "cart"]);
        </script>
        <script src="controllers/sportsStore.js"></script>
        <script src="filters/customFilters.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers/productListControllers.js"></script>
        <script src="components/cart/cart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="sportsStoreCtrl">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a>
        <cart-summary />
      </div>

      <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="data.error">
        Error ({{ data.error.status }}).  The product was not loaded.  <a href="/app.html" class="alert-link">Click here to try again</a>
      </div>

      <ng-include src="'views/productList.html'"></ng-include>

    </body>
</html>
```

-views/cartSummary.html file:

```
<style>
  .navbar-right { float: right !important; margin-right: 5px; }
  .navbar-text { margin-right: 10px; }
</style>
<div class="navbar-right">
  <div class="navbar-text">
    <b>Your Cart:</b>
    {{ itemCount() }} item(s),
    {{ total() | currency }}
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Checkout</a>
</div>
```

-components/cart/cart.js file:

```
angular.module("cart", [])
  .factory("cart", function () {

    var cartData =[];

    return {
      addProduct: function(id, name, price) {
        var addedToExistingItem = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
          if (cartData[i].objectId == id) {
            cartData[i].count++;
            addedToExistingItem = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!addedToExistingItem) {
          cartData.push({
            count: 1, objectId: id, price: price, name: name
          });
        }
      },

      removeProduct: function(id) {
        for (var i = 0; i <cartData.length; i++) {
          if (cartData[i].objectId == id) {
            cartData.splice(i, 1);
            break;
          }
        }
      },

      getProducts: function () {
        return cartData;
      }
    };
  })
  .directive("cartSummary", function(cart) {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "components/cart/cartSummary.html",
      controller: function ($scope) {
        var cartData = cart.getProducts();

        $scope.total = function () {
          var total = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
            total += (cartData[i].price * cartData[i].count);
          }
          return total;
        };

        $scope.itemCount = function () {
          var total = 0;
          for (var i =0; i <cartData.length; i++) {
            total += cartData[i].count;
          }
          return total;
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem!  The author takes the approach of placing parts of the application together by task, hence the "components" directory and when I created the cartSummary.html file, I accidentally placed it in the "views" directory with all of the other partials.  Once I removed it from the "views" directory and placed it within the "cart" directory, it showed up correctly.  Lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

Oh ya, I had this issue too. In the console, for some strange reason, it kept showing that the error is in this line:

```
 cartData.push({count: 1, objectId: id, price: price, name: name});
```

After changing the templateUrl to '**views/cartSummary.html**' from the original: '**components/cart/cartSummary.html**',  it finally worked